# 'Error: Member "mod" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in uint256' when trying to use Chainlink

Tags: solidity, safemath

I got this error while trying to compile

```
    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        randomResult = randomness.mod(20).add(1);
    }
```

I saw it in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=JqZWariqh5s&feature=emb_logo).

Answer (score 1):

use mod operator .

```
uint256 public randomResult;

function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
    randomResult = (randomness % 50) + 1;
}
```

[read it in docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf-best-practices/#:%7E:text=Getting%20a%20random%20number%20within%20a%20range)

Answer (score 1):

The `.add()`/`.sub()`/`.mul()`/`.div()` functions come from a library that implements checked arithmetic. Two popular ones are OpenZeppelin's [SafeMath](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/utilities#math) and dapphub's [ds-math](https://github.com/dapphub/ds-math).

Here's how you would use `SafeMath` for example:

```solidity
import {SafeMath} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract C {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    uint256 public randomResult;

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal {
        randomResult = randomness.mod(20).add(1);
    }
}
```

Note however that you do not really need to use such a library if you're using a recent version of the compiler - since 0.8.0 all the [artithmetic operators are automatically checked against overflow](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#checked-or-unchecked-arithmetic) so you can just use operators directly without losing any checks:

```solidity
randomResult = randomness % 50 + 1;
```